# update null column from select

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, insert, append

I have the below table, approx 3 million rows.

```
at_id  a.at_type_cd   
  1      red           
  2      blue          
  3      yellow
```

I want to add a column, so I did the below.

```
alter table ship.alt
add (src_ind char(1) null)
```

Now I have the below table:

```
at_id    at_type_cd   src_ind
  1      red           (null)
  2      blue          (null)
  3      yellow        (null)
```

All values in the src_ind are null. I want to add values to the src_ind based of a select from another table.

```
merge into &tableschema..alt dest
using (select /* parallel(a,16) */
    x.at_id,
    x.src_ind
    from (select
          a.at_id,
          case 
          when alt.tracks_t is null 
          then 'H' 
          when alt.tracks_at = 1 
          then 'B'
          else 'x'
          end src_ind
          from &tableschema..alt a
          left join (select 
                     alt.at_type,
                     alt.tracks_at
                     from &tableschema..at_tys@db alt
                     where alt.tracks_at <> 0) alt
                     on a.at_type_cd = alt.at_type
                     where 1=1)x ) src
                     on (src.at_id = dest.at_id) 
when matched then                                
 update set
 dest.src_ind = src.src_ind
when not matched then
insert (src_ind)
values (src.src_ind)
```

This takes over two hours on my end. I'm not sure this is correct, using the eyeball test, is there a more efficient way to add column values based on a select?

`update` vs `insert` vs `merge`

Maybe a `insert` with a where `exist`?

Answer (score 1):

Your table `at_tys` seems to be on another database, so I would copy it over, preselecting the rows you'll need:

```
CREATE TABLE local_tys NOLOGGING AS
SELECT at_type, at_tracks_at
  FROM &tableschema..at_tys@db alt
  WHER alt.tracks_at <> 0;
```

Next, I'd write a SELECT that joins your old table without the column and the values of the new column. I did't fully understand your join, so this is just a mockup:

```
SELECT a.at_id, a.at_type_cd, b.
  FROM &tableschema..alt a
  JOIN local_tys b 
    ON a.at_type_cd = b.at_type ....
```

I would then create a table from this query, and once it's built drop the old table and rename the temp table, create index etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
merge into &tableschema..alt dest
using (select 
x.at_id,
x.src_ind
from (select /* parallel(a,16) */
      a.at_id,
      case 
      when alt.tracks_t is null 
      then 'H' 
      when alt.tracks_at = 1 
      then 'B'
      else 'x'
      end src_ind
      from &tableschema..alt a
      left join (select  /* parallel(a,16) */
                 alt.at_type,
                 alt.tracks_at
                 from &tableschema..at_tys@db alt
                 where alt.tracks_at <> 0) alt
                 on a.at_type_cd = alt.at_type
                 where 1=1)x ) src
                 on (src.at_id = dest.at_id) 
when matched then                                
 update set
 dest.src_ind = src.src_ind
 when not matched then
insert (src_ind)
values (src.src_ind) ;
```